# How can I create <area> elements with a loop in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am working on making a calendar with different clickable boxes. These boxes are all part of one larger `.png` image, which is evenly divided into smaller boxes representing different weeks.

These boxes should be made clickable and direct the users to different pages based on which box they are. I am using the  and  tags to do so. However, because there are many boxes which are evenly spaced out, I do not want to type out the  tags by hand, especially because they may change based on how many boxes (years) the user wants.

Below is the `index.html` file, and I already have the first box with its respective coordinates and link. However, I do not want to type out each coordinate and links by hand.

```html
<h1>Your Life Calendar</h1>

<p>Click on a specific box to be transported to that timeframe.</p>

<img src="poster.png" alt="Life Calendar" usemap="#calendar" width="515" height="760" />

<map name="calendar">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,5,5" alt="Week 1" href="#week-1"/>
</map>
```

Ideally, I would like to use a for-loop in JavaScript to dynamically create these  tags based on the user's desired number of boxes. Each box's x-coordinates would increase by 10 each time up to 520, then reset to 0 while the y-coordinates jump by 10 up to the variable `life_expectancy` (e.g. 76).

[image: How the boxes look]

I am unfamiliar with JavaScript, however, and I was unable to achieve the result that I was looking for.

Comment: It would probably make more sense to use hyperlinks (`<a>`) and CSS Grid to align them like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're building, but here's my thoughts:
**Instead of bloating the DOM** with thousands of elements, all you need is:

imagine a *"virtual"* grid...
All we need is a relative click coordinate and some simple math to get the row / col indexes

- Get the **relative** click coordinate **within your element** using:
  `rel_x = event.clientX - event.target.getBoundingClientRect().left`
  `rel_y = event.clientY - event.target.getBoundingClientRect().top`

and some simple math to retrieve the week number and even the color:

```js
const weeks_red = 64; // Say 64 weeks are red.
const cell_size = 10; // px (Including some black area margin)
const cells_row = 14; // cells per row (adjust as your img implies)

const $weekMap = $("#weeksMap");

$weekMap.on("click", (ev) => {

  const bcr = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  const cli = { left: ev.clientX, top: ev.clientY };
  
  // Calculate relative mouse coordinates
  const rel = {
    x: cli.left - bcr.left,
    y: cli.top - bcr.top
  };
  
  // Calculate row, col indexes
  const row = Math.floor(rel.y / cell_size);
  const col = Math.floor(rel.x / cell_size);
  
  const week_idx = row * cells_row + col; // Retrieve 0-based index
  const week_num = week_idx + 1;         // Since indexes are 0 based
  const week_color = week_num > weeks_red ? "green" : "red";
  
  console.clear(); console.log(`Week ${week_num} is ${week_color}`);
  
});
```

```css
#weeksMap {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
Click on a square:<br>
<img id="weeksMap" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XiKD.png">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to highlight every square on hover, all it needs is a parent element and a 5x5 square DIV. On hover, show and position that little *highlight DIV* using `rel.x`, `rel.y` and the Modulo Operator `%` to "snap it to grid".